# DirectX 11 Not Drawing Small Vertex Buffer

Tags: c++, directx-11

I have a problem with my DirectX app. It can't draw primitives like `D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_POINTLIST` or `D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST` when vertices count relatively small value(3 Points to 100 points). Over thousand vertices, it suddenly draws lots of primitives. But not sure it draws them all.

My code looks likes this.

*Main Code:*

1. Fill Vertex Array

> ```
> OurVertices = (VERTEX*)malloc(PointCount * sizeof(VERTEX));
> for (int i = 0; i < PointCount; i++)
> {
>     OurVertices[i] = { RandOm() * i,RandOm() * i ,1.0f ,{abs(RandOm()),abs(RandOm()),abs(RandOm()),1.0f} };
> }
> ```

RandOm():Random value from 0.0f to 1.0f. Multiplied by `i` to get some realistic world coordinates.

2. Vertex Buffer

> ```
> D3D11_BUFFER_DESC bd;
> ZeroMemory(&bd, sizeof(bd));
> bd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;                
> bd.ByteWidth = sizeof(VERTEX)*PointCount;          
> bd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;     
> bd.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;   
> dev->CreateBuffer(&bd, NULL, &pVBuffer);
> ```

VERTEX: struct VERTEX { FLOAT X, Y, Z; FLOAT Color[4]; };

3. Mapping

> ```
> devcon->Map(pVBuffer, NULL, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, NULL, &ms);    
> memcpy(ms.pData, OurVertices, PointCount* sizeof(VERTEX));
> devcon->Unmap(pVBuffer, NULL);
> ```

devcon: ID3D11DeviceContext

4. Render

> ```
> float color[4] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
> devcon->ClearRenderTargetView(backbuffer,color);    
> UINT stride = sizeof(VERTEX);
> UINT offset = 0;
> devcon->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &pVBuffer, &stride, &offset);    
> devcon->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);
>
> devcon->Draw(PointCount, 0);   
> swapchain->Present(0, 0);
> ```

5. Shader

> ```
> VOut VShader(float4 position : POSITION, float4 color : COLOR) {
> VOut output;
> output.position = mul(world, position);
> output.color = color;
> return output; }
> ```

> ```
> float4 PShader(float4 position : SV_POSITION, float4 color : COLOR) : SV_TARGET {
> return color; }
> ```

`XMMatrixOrthographicOffCenterLH` calculated applied using CBuffer as can be seen on shader `world` variable. I think Orthographic projection works fine from my visual observations. There are neither CPU or GPU exceptions. And no warnings.

6. Rasterizer

> ```
> D3D11_RASTERIZER_DESC RasterDesc = {};
> RasterDesc.FillMode = D3D11_FILL_SOLID;
> RasterDesc.CullMode = D3D11_CULL_NONE;
> RasterDesc.DepthClipEnable = TRUE;
> ID3D11RasterizerState* WireFrame=NULL;
> dev->CreateRasterizerState(&RasterDesc, &WireFrame);
> devcon->RSSetState(WireFrame);
> ```

7. Orthographic Projection

> ```
> ID3D11Buffer* g_pConstantBuffer11 = NULL;
> cbuff.world = XMMatrixOrthographicOffCenterLH(SceneY - (ViewPortWidth / 2) 
>     * SceneZoom, SceneY + (ViewPortWidth / 2) * SceneZoom,
>     SceneX - (ViewPortHeight / 2) * SceneZoom, SceneX + (ViewPortHeight / 
>     2) * SceneZoom,-10000.0f, 10000.0f);
>
> D3D11_BUFFER_DESC cbDesc;
> cbDesc.ByteWidth = sizeof(CBUFFER);
> cbDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;
> cbDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_CONSTANT_BUFFER;
> cbDesc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;
> cbDesc.MiscFlags = 0;
> cbDesc.StructureByteStride = 0;
>
> D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA InitData;
> InitData.pSysMem = &cbuff;
> InitData.SysMemPitch = 0;
> InitData.SysMemSlicePitch = 0;
>
> dev->CreateBuffer(&cbDesc, &InitData,&g_pConstantBuffer11);
>
> devcon->VSSetConstantBuffers(0, 1, &g_pConstantBuffer11);
> ```

Comment: First, make sure you check every function that returns an ``HRESULT`` with ``SUCCEEDED``, ``FAILED``, or [ThrowIfFailed](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ThrowIfFailed). There are many points of failure and you need to validate them all. Second, you are not explicitly setting a rasterizer state, so you are defaulting to 'back-face culling'. For a bunch of random vertices like this, you should set a RasterState object with a cull mode of ``.CullMode = D3D11_CULL_NONE``. Also, where do you set your world matrix constant?

Comment: You may want to check out the [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started).

Comment: I erased error handling codes from the code in the question to avoid unreadable code. i made it simple. And i am going to edit the code in the question for `Rasterizer` and Ortho matrix.

Comment: Also it is weird that, no other shaders works with my code. I tried tesellation using this code for ~50M random vertices and it is just plain black screen. No primitives rendered. And no gpu exceptions nor shader errors.  I tested gpu and cpu exceptions and shader compile errors. Design time errors and runtime exceptions occur. So that is a good sign i believe :P I think i am going to ask seperate question from this one.